# How to change viewport on iPhone/iPad?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, html

I have a canvas element that is 608 pixels wide and am trying to get both the iPhone and iPad to zoom-in so that this fills the screen.

I have been experimenting with various values but none seem to work on both devices. Here is what I currently have (works on iPhone but looks small on iPad):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=608; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;" />
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it, need to ensure that the minimum and maximum scale are set properly because otherwise it is constrained!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=608, maximum-scale=1.5, user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; width=device-width;">
```

Or you may need to use javascript to get the current viewport scale, this article may help:  http://menacingcloud.com/?c=viewportScale

Comment: Thanks for your help! but I found that I was setting the content parameters incorrectly.

Comment: No worries!  Glad you sorted it!